# How to sum selected values in option tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have a v-for loop and 7 different documents from mongo database. Every document contains one food and for each food it has specific number of calories. And I want to sum all the selected calories. For example I got a variable `food.calorie_number`. Okay so I have something like this:

```
<tr>
   <td v-for="(food) in fetch_breakfast.slice(8,15)" :key=food.id>Meal <p style="border-top: 3px solid #dddddd;">
   <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
       <option selected>Select your food</option>
       <option v-bind:value="food.id">{{food.food}}</option>
       <!-- Every meal has food.calorie_number -->
       <option value="3"></option>
   </select>
   </p></td>
       <p>Calorie sum: {{Sum}}</p>
</tr>
```

I wanted to do something like this: `Sum = Sum + food.calorie_number` but i didn't get the final solution because I don't know how to do it for a specific element generated by v-for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly try like following snippet (with computed and method for selection) :

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      fetch_breakfast: [{id: 1, food: 'apple', calorie_number: 80}, {id: 2, food: 'peach', calorie_number: 70}, {id: 3, food: 'carrot', calorie_number: 90}],
      selected: []
    }
  },
  computed: {
    sum() {
      return this.selected.reduce((acc, curr) => acc + curr.calorie_number, 0)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getSum(food) {
      const idx = this.selected.findIndex(s => s.id === food.id)
      idx > -1 ? this.selected.splice(idx, 1) : this.selected.push(food)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td v-for="food in fetch_breakfast" :key=food.id>Meal 
        <p>
          <select class="form-select" @change="getSum(food)">
             <option selected>Select your food</option>
             <option :value="food.id">{{ food.food }}</option>
          </select>
        </p>
      </td>
      <p>Calorie sum: {{ sum }}</p>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I work a little differently than the example, I'm trying to retrieve the values I have in the mongodb database, does the logic on this issue remain the same?

Comment: @Jan Tuđan hey mate, yes same thing, just fetch data and pass it to your table and then use computed to get sum and method to select food, like in example :)

Comment: Hmm, when I try to search by id I think the id can't be fetched because Mongo has randomly generaded id-s, I try something like this: ```s => s.id === this.fetch_breakfast.id``` so every time I get ```NaN``` for sum. Or somehow array does not match the selected one defined in the v-for loop.

Answer (score 0):

First you have v-for on the wrong element because that way it will return 7 select. if you want to have seven options put v-for in select but to have a default option that is not affected by the loop put in option like this:

**then do your logic and fetch in either computed value**

```js
var selector = new Vue({
  el: '#selector',
  data: {
    selected: null,
    meals: [
       {'id':1,
      "name":"food_name_1",
      "calories":"1.6g"
      },
      {'id':2,
      "name":"food_name_g",
      "calories":"1.8g"
      },
      {'id':3,
      "name":"food_name_v",
      "calories":"1.9g"
      },
      {'id':9,
      "name":"food_name_v",
      "calories":"1.66g"
      },
      {'id':11,
      "name":"food_name_y",
      "calories":"1.1g"
      },
      ]
    
  },
  
  computed:{
  
  selected_food(){
  let id = this.selected
  let selected_meal = this.meals.find(meal => meal.id === id)
  return selected_meal
  
  }
  
  }
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="selector">
  <select :default="0" v-model="selected">
  <option selected="selected"  :value=null>select meal</option>
    <option v-for="(meal, key) in meals" :key=key :value="meal.id">
      {{ meal.name }}
    </option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  
  
  
  <div v-if="selected">
  <span  > Selected food : {{selected_food.name}}</span> </br>
  <span  > Selected food Calory : {{selected_food.calories}}</span>
  </div>
  <span v-else>Please select a meal</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Well I want to use 7 selects because every of that meal will be selected in each days of week and I want to calculate calories of every selected meal for a single day.